# Prevent full table scan if no matching records

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a MySQL table with four columns: `col1`, `col2`, `col3`, and `col4` out of which `col1`, `col2`, and `col3` formed an index.

```
+------------+------------+----------+--------------+-------------+
| Table      | Non_unique | Key_name | Seq_in_index | Column_name |
+------------+------------+----------+--------------+-------------+
| test_table |          0 | PRIMARY  |            1 | col1        |
| test_table |          0 | PRIMARY  |            2 | col2        |
| test_table |          0 | PRIMARY  |            3 | col3        |
+------------+------------+----------+--------------+-------------+
```

Now I want to fetch records from this table where the `col4` is `null` in order to process batch-wise, let's say fetch 5 records, process and update the `col4` with a `non-null` value.

```
select * from test_table WHERE col4 is NULL limit 5;
```

but the issue is that this query is performing a full table scan in case there are no matching records for the above query.

I would like to know an efficient way to prevent this full table scan scenario.

Comment: Did you try to add index on `col4`?

Comment: @Alexey, I prefer a solution without having to add an index on `col4` as there are more than 80 million records in the table.

Comment: Moreover, you need an index on `col4` if you are querying on this column.

Comment: @Lakmal An index *is* the solution to this.

Comment: You need to use index if you don't want to perform full table scan. Moreover, indexes are always updated when there is a data inserted.